# Azure Function Breaks with environment variable HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to get the azure function to call to go through a proxy. However, I am using an azure library that requires HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY  to be set before connection.

The problem arises when I set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY as environment variables the Azure function host fails to start at all. I then tried setting the variable only during the function call time then this broke MSI authentication to other resources.

How can I get specific calls to go through the Proxy while others stay out of the proxy?

Comment: Don't set it globally for the app, instead set it inside a script you call at start instead of the actual binary. If you want to have them as environment variables still, call them something else and remap them inside the start script

Comment: This is breaking MSI authentication in Azure when done this way